# no match for operator >> in std::cin

Tags: c++, debugging, operator-overloading

I have a class employee

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class employee
{
    public:

            double operator + (employee);
            istream& operator>> (istream&);

            employee(int);
            double getSalary();

    private:

           double salary;

};

int main()
{  
  employee A(400);
  employee B(800);

  employee C(220);

  cin>>C;

}

employee::employee(int salary)
{
    this->salary = salary;
}


double employee::operator + (employee e)
{
    double total;

    total = e.salary + this->salary;

    return total;    
}


double employee::getSalary()
{
    return this->salary;
}

istream& employee::operator>> (istream& in)
{
    in>>this->salary;

    return in;

}
```

I am trying to overload the input operator >> to read in the employee object but i am getting the following error

> no match for operator >> in std::cin

What am i doing wrong ???

**edit: I know how to do it through a friend function , i am now trying to learn how to do it through a member function**

Comment: The way you defined it you need to write `C >> cin` (although that's a bit weird).

Comment: @KerrekSB, not just a bit weird. Such flagrant misuse of operator overloading should be punishable by death. Or at least mockery and ridicule :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: To be fair, its hard to see how you could *not* abuse operator overloading in the context of `>>`, standard library not excused :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I know how to do it through a friend function , i am now trying to learn how to do it through a member function**

You can't.

For a binary `operator@` and objects `A a` and `B b`, the syntax `a @ b` will call **either** a non-member function of the form `operator@(A,B)` **or** a member function of the form `A::operator@(B)`. Nothing else.

So to make `std::cin >> C` work it must be as a member of `std::istream`, but since you can't modify `std::istream` you can't implement `operator>>` as a member function.

(Unless you want to be weird and unconventional and write `C << std::cin` or `C >> std::cin`, but if you do that other programmers will hate you for being confusing and unconventional. Do not do this.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare it thusly:

```
class employee
{
public:
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, employee& employee);
}; // eo class employee
```

Implementation:

```
std::istream& employee::operator >> (std::istream& is, employee& employee)
{
    is >> employee.salary; // this function is a friend, private members are visible.
    return is;
};
```

As a side note, it's generally a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) to do `using namespace std;` within a header file.

Comment: assuming i dont want to do it through a friend function , how do i go about doing it?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to do it through a friend function?  If not you could put it in to a temporary variable and then call a method `setSalary()` which you haven't yet defined.

Comment: I already know how to do it through the friend function , i am  unsure of how to do it through a member function hence i want to learn it also

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we cannot declare operator << inside class declaration. I've tried it and it is OK.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
    int field;
};

istream& operator >> (istream& cin, foo& a){
    cin >> a.field;
    return cin;
}

foo a;

main(){
    cin >> a;
}
```

Comment: You can, please see my answer.  This also keeps related code together rather than in the global namespace.

Comment: @Moo-Juice : OK, I agree with you.